# .NET Core - SQL Server Data Filtering By Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, impersonation

I am currently working with a Windows Intranet application where based on Windows Authentication, data residing in a SQL Server database is filtered using row-level security.  Each domain account is assigned specific access rights which is then checked with a filter predicate inside of SQL Server, modifying what the user can see.

The application uses .NET Framework and is deployed to Windows IIS and uses ASP.NET Impersonation.  This allows queries to be executed as the user rather than the application itself.  Data is then filtered on retrieval based on that users defined access rights.

Unfortunately .NET Core does not natively support Windows Impersonation.

Leveraging .NET Core, SQL Server & Windows Authentication, what are my options for customizing a user's access rights based on their Windows Login without the use of Impersonation?

I am aware that Impersonation is technically possible in .NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

But I have read through many github forum posts expressing numerous issues with this method.

From a design standpoint, what additional options do I have to construct this type of flow, where a user is credentialed based on their Windows Login which will then determine the type of data they retrieve from the database?

Comment: `Unfortunately .NET Core does not natively support Windows Authentication.` wrong. Both the old System.Data.SqlClient and the newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient work fine not only with Windows Authentication but Azure AD as well.

Comment: @mason on the contrary, databases offer several levels of permission, from login to table, columns and individual rows. You can say that *impersonation* isn't the correct choice, but if you really care about security, you'll use permissions in the database as well.

Comment: @mason besides, allowing the web app account to access everything in the database and try to restrict operations in the web app isn't the most secure design. Should someone hack the web app, they'll be able to read everything in the database.

Comment: What type of machine and operating system are you using?  The issue is not Core but the operating system.

Comment: `I am aware that Impersonation is technically possible in .NET Core ... But I have read through many github forum posts expressing numerous issues with this method.` .NET Framework used impersonation as well. Have you actually tried this? Did you encounter any actual errors? Impersonation isn't enabled by default because the requirements aren't the same they were back in 2002 - ASP.NET Core is cross-platform and web apps use different authentication mechanisms nowadays. Even with Azure AD it's not enough to use Windows impersonation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edit my original post.  What I meant to say was .NET Core does not natively support Windows **Impersonation**

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, we are currently implementing the above method with .NET Framework leveraging Impersonation.  Data is secured at the database level, and a user's Window's Login is the determining factor in what they see.

The post was made to see what the options were to have data restricted inside a table based on Windows Authentication using .NET Core rather than .NET Framework.

Comment: @jdweng This is all being done on a Windows environment in a Windows Intranet Application.  The goal is to see how to implement data access controls from a database using Windows Authentication & .NET Core rather than .NET Framework.

Comment: I understood that from the start. The point is that .NET Framework didn't use magic either, it actually called the impersonation methods itself. That was on by default back in the 2000s, because that's what made sense. Especially for the CRUD web apps created with WebForms. Things are different now, so impersonation isn't on by default. Even for complex WebForms apps though, impersonation wasn't the best option.

Comment: Have you tried impersonation in .NET Core yet? Have you encountered any problems?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suppose that begs the question then, what are better design options under the context I've described?  Windows intranet application, .NET Core, Windows IIS, where a user doesn't type credentials, but is authorized through their current Windows Login.  Then based on this login, database tables are filtered for them to see their proper data?

And to answer your other question, I have tried to use impersonation on .NET Core but the failure is surely due to my incorrect implementation.

Comment: It should automatically work if the database is setup correctly and the connection string uses Integrated Security - true, and you are using the same account on both core and server. A group account need to be setup so core and server machines both are the same account.

Comment: @jdweng It automatically works with .NET Framework using Windows Impersonation.  This does not automatically work in .NET Core.

`ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation. Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity.`

[ASP.NET Core Impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation)

Comment: Why are you impersonating?  If you logged into Windows Core with an account that is recognized by server than there is no need to impersonate,  To impersonate you would bee ADMIN rights.

Comment: @jdweng I am impersonating because SQL Server sees all requests as coming from a service account rather than the user themselves.  When ASP.Net Impersonation is on, the requests which would have come from a service account are now impersonated by the user which allows them to see the appropriate data.  User A and User B can access the same table, but both will see different results based on a security access predicate residing within SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you using a Service Account?  With Service Account You have to impersonate which requires an Admin.  VS doesn't automatically use ADMIN unless you start by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The right way of doing this is to create a group account.  Usually companies are already using Group Policy and there is a group.  Then make database use Group Account for privilege's. Put al user into group.  Use Integrated Security = true in connection string.  Then everything will work.  You will not need to Impersonate.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, but I'm just not understanding what you're trying to say here.  The point is, if I make a group account and assign that group account as the IIS App Pool, that group account will be the one making the query to SQL Server.  With Row Level Security, Domain\John, Domain\Bob and Domain\GroupAccount will all get different results when querying the database.  This is why ASP.NET Impersonation was necessary.  I need the application to make the query as the individual user, not as a group account.  It's not only about gaining access.  It matters who specifically is making the request.

Comment: You can start the service with the database account so you do not need to impersonate.  Or create an executable that runs with database account and call from the service.

Comment: @jdweng I appreciate the suggestions, but probably at my own fault, have no idea what you're suggesting.  I've never seen anything over the past year suggesting anything using these terms in the sequence you're referencing.  While I don't doubt there are alternative ways of doing this, everything I have read in my research implies some level of impersonation is needed, whether it's natively implemented through .NET Framework, manually called in .NET Core, or queries to SQL with EXECUTE () AS LOGIN statements.

Comment: @jdweng And to clarify, regardless of if "Integrated Security = 'TRUE'" is set in the DB Connection string. ASP.NET Core will NOT connect to the database as the windows authenticated user.  ASP.NET Core will run the database queries directly from the service that connected to the database.  Meaning I can give all of the users access through this group, but they all will have the same access.  They will not be re-identified at their Windows Authentication level once their group account connects them to to instance of SQL Server.  With row-level security, this is necessary.

Comment: A service runs as default with a System account.  Using Roles a service CAN pass the client privileges to the database. Without Roles the service can be set to run with any user account.  The user account privileges will be used to make the connection to the database.

Comment: When services connect to databases there are two types 1) Ones where a private credentials is used to connect 2) Ones where client credentials are used.  Neither case is it necessary to impersonate.  Impersonation should only be used by ADMINS when it is necessary to look like a particular user.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately I don't follow the flow of what you're representing nor are my searches finding anything relating to Service/Roles/Client Privileges/Database.  Do you know of any documentation or tutorials online which follow the design pattern that you're referencing?  All I know if is either the IIS Identity Pool accesses the database or during ASP.NET Impersonation, the Windows Authenticated User is passed along to act as the Identity accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

Impersonation will additionally require [Kerberos Constrained Delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview) if the SQL Server is on a different server from IIS.

As an alternative to Windows impersonation, you can use SQL Server impersonation.  After opening the connection using a service account (ie the IIS App Pool identity), run [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to impersonate the end user inside SQL Server, and before closing the connection [REVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to end the impersonation.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I run my security testing using SQL Server impersonation and EXECUTE AS statements, but never thought to do away with Windows Impersonation and set the underlying requests to be done using this.  I'm currently using Datatables so I would have to see how to modify the select statements and insert the identity of the Windows user as part of this statement.

Comment: See roles : var skillNode = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("tr")
    .Where(t => t.GetAttributeValue("id", "")